# NetBeans 6.8: "Java Web" not an option

Tags: jsp, tomcat, netbeans, ubuntu, installation

I'm following this tutorial to set up an existing set of files for a web application, run on Tomcat6, packaged through NetBeans on Ubuntu 10:

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps.html#setting

And I'm stopped at the first step because it says to create a new project, and under categories select Java Web.  This isn't a category available to me.  What do I need to do to get started with a web application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to make sure that you have the right plugins installed.

Click on Tools>Plugins. Under Available Plugins look for Java Web and EE  and install them.

Alternatively, when you download Netbeans you have the option to choose the appropriate package for yourself. You can select the package that includes Java Web and EE. It comes with Tomcat 6 and GlassFish server.

Comment: Sorry but nothing comes when I go under **available plugins**

Comment: Nabin you need to check you connection under preferences. Are you behind a proxy etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you have NetBeans 8.2 or greater installed so you must choose Oracle Cloud from Avaible plugins , it was my case so it may be yours too ;)