# Can't create Java Web Application in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, web-applications

I want to write a java web application using NetBeans 7.0.1, but i can't find the option `Java Web` in `File -> New Project`. Do i need to get any special Java edition to do that?

Comment: Welcome to Superusers. You might want to ask your question in [webapps.se]. Superuser is aimed more at personal computer hardware, software and home networking.

Comment: Does `JApplet` or `Applet` appear when you go to **File > New File > Java**?

Comment: Also, have you used Netbeans before? Did you install a [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)?

Comment: Your question is duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102512/netbeans-6-8-java-web-not-an-option

Comment: @AdelBoutros, not necessarily because that question is about version 6.8, not 7.0+.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

1. Go to the Tools menu and select Plugins.
2. Click on the "Available Plugins" tab.
3. Check the box for "Java EE Base" (note: on older NetBeans versions, the plugin to install was called "Java Web Applications").
4. Click the "Install" button.
5. Click your way through the dialogs until the plugin and its dependencies are installed.
6. Restart the IDE.

You should now find "Java Web" in File -> New Project.

Comment: Your answer is duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102512/netbeans-6-8-java-web-not-an-option

Comment: You just repeated what the answer of that question suggested. Do not take credit for others' answers.

Comment: @AdelBoutros I know it's easier to click the downvote button than it is to read but you should at least take the time to consider what you're writing.  For example, my answer gives the exact title of the plugin necessary. How did I steal that from the other answer?  I didn't because I took the time to install the basic version of NetBeans 7.0.1, then install the plugins necessary to enable Java web application development. I had NB 6.8 on this computer so I figured I'd kill two birds with one stone: upgrade my installation and help someone out.

Comment: Can't he deduct an answer from the question? That's why it's a duplicate

Comment: My answer is not a duplicate because: 1. NetBeans' major version number is different between the two questions. 2. The answer you claim I was taking credit for states, "Under Available Plugins look for Java Web and EE and install them". If you'd bothered to do any research you'd see that "Java Web and EE" is a category and includes plugins like "Struts", "Spring Web MVC", and "Shale Dialog Module". He does not need to install all of those, only the single plugin I named, which was not named in the answer you claimed I stole. How I stole something that was never there remains a mystery...

Comment: All you had to do was telling him to see the other question and tell him that he only need to install one plugin. But apparently you like points. Good luck

Comment: Thank you. I believe it should be noted that in order for your answer to work for me, I had to go to Tools > Plugins > Settings  and click "Netbeans Distributions". Before I did that, I could not see "Java Web Applications" on my list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer dude, you can't please them all.

Comment: For NetBeans 8.2 use kangaswad's answer. The plugin to install is Java EE Base.

Answer (score 31):

1. Go to the Tools menu and select Plugins.
2. Click on the "Available Plugins" tab.
3. Check the box for "Java EE Base".
4. Click the "Install" button.
5. Select "Web Projects" from plugin list
6. Check the term & condition checkbox
7. Click next and wait while NetBeans downloading the plugin
8. Restart IDE

Comment: For NetBeans 8.2 basic installation this is the correct method, the plugin is called  "Java EE Base", not "Java Web Applications".

Answer (score 18):

My answer will provide images for you to understand easily.

Go to **Tools** -> **Plugins** like this image

[image: Plugins]

In **Plugins** windows, select **Available Plugins** tab, choose and install **Java EE Base** like this image 
[image: JavaEEBase]

Now just follow the instruction and install the plugin, when it's done, restart the Netbeans, then you can create Java Web Application like this image
[image: Create web]

Answer (score 7):

I had problems while finding the plugins under the **Available plugins** tab. The reason was under the **settings** tab, the three checkboxes were unchecked. I checked them all and then I can see the plugins under the **Available plugins** Tab.

And then I followed the steps mentioned in other answers. Hope this is also useful to this context.

Answer (score 6):

Well, maybe you cant find Java Web in the installation list, so, search for Java EE Base, in Netbeans 7.x is the option, and includes the comment that includes Java Web and EE.

regards

Answer (score 0):

If you have NetBeans 8.2+ and installed the EE edition, open the plugin panel from `Tools -> Plugins`. Go to the installed tab and check the `Java EE Base` plugin. Then activate that plugin.

If you need other options as well the select all the plugins under the `Web and Java EE` category and activate them.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Above mentioned thing didn't worked for me.

I have installed multiple JDK (JDK version 8 and 9) due to which Netbeans 8.2 might not working as expected and then I was unable to create project.

Then I removed JDK9 and cleared cache from \Users\admin\AppData in windows.

Then I was able to create Java Project.