# cannot create web site in Netbeans

Tags: java, web-applications, netbeans

I have just installed JDK 7u45 & NetBeans 7.4 together .But When i try to create a java web application

```
File -> New Project ->Categoies
```

There is no Java web application option.So  I have followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773113/cant-create-java-web-application-in-netbeans)  steps But in the Available Plugins There is  no checkbox named Java Web Applications .What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you did not download correct Netbeans bundle. You should use `Java EE` enabled Netbeans.

Go to the Netbeans download [link](https://netbeans.org/downloads/). Download `Java EE` supported Netbeans and than try again.